# Why won't my CSS media queries and styles work

Tags: css, media-queries, media

ive created three media queries on my stylesheet. the first two are alright but the last one isnt. id like to know why?

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 600px){..styles..}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px){..styles..}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1000px){..styles..}
```

Comment: Seems correct, maybe with more relevant code we can help you

Comment: Maybe because your screen is narrower than 800px?

Comment: Stack Overflow requires that questions requesting debugging help include enough code to reproduce the issue in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess because your queries overlap.

should be:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 50px) and (max-width: 600px){..styles..}
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 800px){..styles..}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1000px){..styles..}
```

EDIT: Also, the first `min-width:50px` and last `max-width:1000px` are unnecessary. Unless you have a screen size smaller than `50px`, which I can't imagine, or you have another query beyond `1000px`.

In fact, you could remove the entire first query and just keep the second and third. It would accomplish the same thing.